# Receber variável no php e chamar função Ajax passando essa variável

Tags: php, ajax

Vou explicar melhor esse meu post, creio não ter sido claro na questão.
Hoje, tenho uma página onde efetuo uma busca por determinado termo e o resultado me é apresentado em seguida, uma pesquisa `AJAX Live Search`.

A página está assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O código está assim, tenho um campo `input` com o ID definido como `Termo`, vejam:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control required" id="Termo" value="" onkeyup="sendRequest();" placeholder="Informe uma palavra">
```

A função chamada está assim:

```
// BUSCA DINÂMICA
function sendRequest() {
    var Termo = document.getElementById('Termo').value;
    if (Termo.length > 2) {
        var url = "pBuscaRamais.php?Termo=" + Termo;
        ajax.open('GET', url, true);
        ajax.onreadystatechange = ajaxListener;
        ajax.send(null);
    }
}

function ajaxListener() {
    if (ajax.readyState == 1) {
        // INSERIR GIF DE CARREGAMENTO
    } else if (ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200) {
        ramais.innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
        // REINICIALIZANDO A FUNÇÃO APÓS O RETORNO
        // DETALHES scripts.js
        _toggle();
    }
}
```

O que estou tentando fazer, a pesquisa por um termpo a partir de uma outra página, passando o input para a página iBuscaRamais.php, recuperar a variável, chamar uma função e retornar a pesquisa na página iBuscaRamais.php.

A página dessa chamada é essa:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O código `html` da mesma está assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou recuperando a variável Termo na página iBuscaRamais.php, a variável recuperado está com o conteúdo digitado, o problema é como chamar a função que posso fazer a pesquisa e me retornar, nessa pesquisa não é uma `AJAX Live Search`

Estou recuperando a variável e tentando passar a variável assim:

```
if (isset($_POST['Termo'])) {
    $Termo = $_POST['Termo'];   
echo "
function loadDoc($Termo){
}
"  
}
```

E a função chamada é essa:

```
function loadDoc() {
    var Termo = "";

    console.log(Termo);

    var url = "pBuscaRamais.php?Termo=" + Termo;
    ajax.open('GET', url, true);
    ajax.onreadystatechange = ajaxBuscaIndex;
    ajax.send(null);
}

function ajaxBuscaIndex() {
    if (ajax.readyState == 1) {
        // INSERIR GIF DE CARREGAMENTO
    } else if (ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200) {
        ramais.innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
        // REINICIALIZANDO A FUNÇÃO APÓS O RETORNO
        // DETALHES scripts.js
        _toggle();
    }
}
```

No meu console não me é apresentado nenhuma mensagem de erro, mas não funciona.

Comment: Esse $_POST está vindo através de um action?

Comment: Coloca todo o trecho, onde está sendo passado os valores para a variável $Termo, se tiver um errinho bobo fica fácil de ver...

Comment: Bom vamos por partes, faz um teste ali no $_POST, e vê se a variável está vindo... Não se já fez mas...Dessa forma vamos afunilando o erro... Dá um echo onde tá recebendo a variável...

Comment: Olá  @MagicHat, obrigado pela dica, sim, a variável está com valor.

Comment: Menos 1 problema, então o problema está na chamada da função ou na função em si...vamo lá...Aparece algum erro ?

Comment: Num tá faltando, desculpe se estiver errado, inicializar o request?
var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();

Comment: Não coloque no post, mas estou inicializando sim @MagicHat.

Comment: hum... bota lá tmb , pra irmos acompanhando, todo detalhe é relevante.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No PHP faça assim:

`if (isset($_POST['Termo'])) {
   $Termo = $_POST['Termo'];
   echo '<script> loadDoc("'.$Termo.'") </script>;
}`

E no seu JS:

```
function loadDoc(meuTermo) {
var Termo = meuTermo;

console.log(Termo);

var url = "pBuscaRamais.php?Termo=" + Termo;
ajax.open('GET', url, true);
ajax.onreadystatechange = ajaxBuscaIndex;
ajax.send(null);
}

function ajaxBuscaIndex() {
if (ajax.readyState == 1) {
    // INSERIR GIF DE CARREGAMENTO
} else if (ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200) {
    ramais.innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
    // REINICIALIZANDO A FUNÇÃO APÓS O RETORNO
    // DETALHES scripts.js
    _toggle();
}
}
```

Comment: Olá @Will Knippelberg, valeu pela dica, mas a impressão é que a função não está sendo invocada, no meu js coloquei um console.log para exibir uma mensagem e nem isso aparece.

Comment: Da uma olhada na edição que fiz. O Erro tava na invocação no seu PHP

Comment: Olá @Will Knippelberg, estou recebendo a seguinte mensagem no meu console: iBuscaRamais.php:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: loadDoc is not defined, tenho uma ideia do que pode ser, mas não consegui resolver.

Answer (score 1):

Brother, como você está mandando os dados via `form` eu recomendo o seguinte

`data : $("form").serialize()`

assim todos os dados do formulário vão para a variavel `data` e ai vc pode trabalhar isso com o ajax...

Espero ter ajudado, abraço.

Answer (score 0):

Creio que agora entendi o que está querendo. veja se é isto, fiz um teste simples e funcionou aqui.

```
<script>
function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "response.txt", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
</script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form method="post" action="">

<input type="text" value="" placeholder="Nome*" maxlength="100" class="form-control required" name="Termo" />
</br >
<input type="text" value="" placeholder="Entreposto*" maxlength="100" class="form-control required" name="busca_ramal[Entreposto]" />
</br >
<input type="submit" value="BUSCAR" class="btn btn-success btn-block" />
</form>

<div id="demo"><h2>Aqui é o response</h2></div>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['Termo'])) {
$Termo = $_POST['Termo']; 
 echo '<script type="text/javascript">
            loadDoc();
        </script>'; 
}
?>


</body>
</html>
```

response.txt

```
Response ok !
```

**Receber a variável:**

```
    function sendRequest() {

    /*var Termo = "RECEBER A VARIÁVEL PHP AQUI";
    coloque um id="id_input" no input*/
    var Termo = document.getElementById("id_input").value;
    var url = "pBuscaRamais.php?Termo=" + Termo;
    ajax.open('GET', url, true);
    ajax.onreadystatechange = ajaxListener;
    ajax.send(null);    
    }
```

Veja se é isso, qualquer coisa comenta.

Comment: Olá @MagicHat, me diz uma coisa, onde você está passando a variável "Termo" para a página de pesquisa em PHP?

Comment: @adventistapr Nussa mano, acho que tô precisando usar óculos, isso que vc colocou em letra miúscula..kkk vou editar